# Is "Second Breakfast" only in the movie version of LOTR?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

There is a cute moment in the [movie](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0Est7seheM) where Pippin asks about "Second Breakfast".  I recall food being important to Hobbits, but I don't recall a similar scene in the book.  The movie scene is very memorable, I think I would remember if it was in the book also.

Is the scene and/or the concept of "Second Breakfast" unique to the movie?

Comment: It's not even unique to Tolkien (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_breakfast), although the phrase is not so cutely contradictory in German since "break fast" inherently means "first meal" whereas "Früh" just means "early".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, it's in the books as well

**The Hobbit :**

> *Bilbo began to whistle loudly and to forget about the night before. In fact he was just sitting down to a nice little second breakfast in
>   the dining-room by the open window, when in walked Gandalf.*

**Fellowship of the Ring :**

> *As for the Hobbits of the Shire ... And laugh they did, and eat, and drink, often and heartily, being fond of simple jests at all times,
>   and of six meals a day (when they could get them). They were
>   hospitable and delighted in parties, and in presents, which they gave
>   away freely and eagerly accepted.*

Comment: +1. I was just looking for that half remembered quote from LotR to add my own answer, but you beat me to it. :)

Comment: @avnershahar-kashtan - I've got the books in my calibre library where I can search them easily.

Comment: What was the sixth meal? I remember breakfast, second breakfast, lunch, dinner and supper.

Comment: @johnp - you've missed elevenses

Comment: @Richard - Thanks, I knew there was a second lunch type thing but couldn't remember the name.

Comment: The movie line included afternoon tea as well. Very British. That sequence was one of the non-textual adjustments made that I approve of because it replaced authorial voice narration in the text (i.e. "tell me") with a properly characterized dialog conveying the same thing ("show me").

Comment: The six meals aren't explicitly named, so "Second Breakfast" might not be a name of a meal in the way we understand "breakfast" to be. It's not really said either way, but the idea behind it is certainly there.